# Can we Change the default fieldname parent_id to FldParentId in Cake Php for Find('thread') statement?

Tags: cakephp

I have changed the fieldname parent_id to FldParentId in a Table admin_menus. I want to select all the sub menus under a particular parent_id. but it gives an notice like

"Notice (8): Undefined index: parent_id [CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 2337]".
So my question is that can I change this fieldname from parent_id to FldParentId.Is that possible..or I have to keep this fieldname as parent_id??

Please help me out..I need to know dat..
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no option to overwrite the key to use for the `find('threaded')` method you need to keep the fieldname like the way CakePHP wants it or you could overwrite the method used by CakePHP in your AppModel.

See`cake/libs/model/model.php` on line `2311` where you can find the `_findThreaded` function to see how this is working.

I would just rename the field if you have no other dependencies on it.

Comment: That should probably reported as a bug. The TreeBehavior is configurable, the related find method isn't...

Comment: I have done as you told me..I have overwrite the function _findThreaded() in app_model.php.but it stil give me the same result as berore.  Notice (8): Undefined index: parent_id [CORE/cake/libs/model/model.php, line 2337]> .I have all parent_id with FldParentId but same same problem is still there..how to overcome this problem??? @Tim

Comment: Please tell us what exactly is in line 2337 in the file `/cake/libs/model/model.php`